# Subtract one Day from date when inside a time interval

Tags: java, android, date

I try to subtract one day when the time inside 0:00 am - 12:00 am.

ex: `2012-12-14 06:35 am` => `2012-12-13`

I have done a function and It's work. But my question is any other better code in this case? Much simpler and easy to understand.

```
public String getBatchDate() {

    SimpleDateFormat timeFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("H");
    int currentTime = Integer.parseInt(timeFormatter.format(new Date()));
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
    String Date = dateFormatter.format(new Date());

    if ( 0 <= currentTime && currentTime <= 12){
        try {
            Calendar shiftDay = Calendar.getInstance();
            shiftDay.setTime(dateFormatter.parse(Date));
            shiftDay.add(Calendar.DATE, -1); 
            Date = dateFormatter.format(shiftDay.getTime());
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.d("BatchDate:", Date);
    }

    return Date;

}
```

THANKS,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Calendar shiftDay = Calendar.getInstance();
shiftDay.setTime(new Date())
if(shiftDay.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) <= 12){
    shiftDay.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
}
//your date format
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the Calendar class to inspect and modify the Date.

```
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(); // initializes calendar with current time
cal.setTime(date); // initializes the calender with the specified Date
```

Use `cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)` to find out the hour within the day.

Use `cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1)` to set the date one day back.

Use `cal.getTime()` to get a new Date instance of the time that was stored in the calendar.

Answer (score 1):

As with nearly all questions with regard to Date / Time, try [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/)

```
public String getBatchDate() {
    DateTime current = DateTime.now();
    if (current.getHourOfDay() <= 12)
           current = current.minusDays(1); 
    String date = current.toString(ISODateTimeFormat.date());
    Log.d("BatchDate:" + date);
    return date;
}
```